# How can I delete na values from specific columns in a data set?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, na, tidyr

I have a dataset with 28 variables, and I want to exclude all missing data from 4 of these variables.

If I use `na.omit` in the whole dataset, I'll lose data from these columns. What I want is to get the examples with complete data and exclude rows in which there is an `NA` value in this 4 variables.

Also, what if I wanted to exclude `NA` values in these 4 variables so each of them have no more than 5% missing data?

Comment: `library(tidyr); df %>% drop_na(your_column_names)`

Comment: `x[complete.cases(x[1:3]),]` for the first three columns

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tidyr` package:

```
library(tidyr)
df %>% drop_na(col_a, col_b, col_c, col_d)
```

For the second part, you probably need to get different subsets and combine them together. AFAIK